# Formatting column number in a dynamyc view panel in a xpage

Tags: xpages

I'm using dynamic view panel in XPages. The problem that formatting the number does not follow the format defined in view column.
I searched and found that the way to format the number is through a customizer bean. I've Got some code examples of this bean, though none of them had an example with formatting a column containing a number.
Does anyone have an example of this treatment formatting?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a code snippet from a `getValueAsString()` method from an `ExtendedViewColumnConverter` class that handles number formatting based on the user locale.

The code assumes that the variable `currentLocale` contains the user locale. currentLocale is an instance of java.util.Locale.Locale and I assume that you have logik that handles this e.g. as part of a user bean. If not, then one way of getting the current locale is to do this:

```java
Locale currentLocale = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getLocale();
```

You should of course have an already working customizer bean (that extends `DominoViewCustomizer`).

```java
public static class ExtendedViewColumnConverter extends ViewColumnConverter {

    ...

    @Override
    public String getValueAsString(final FacesContext context, final UIComponent component, final Object value) {

        if (value instanceof Number) {
            NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(currentLocale);
            DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat) nf;
            df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
            switch (this.colDef.getNumberFmt()) {
            case ViewColumn.FMT_GENERAL: {
                // no further formatting needed
                break;
            }
            case ViewColumn.FMT_FIXED: {
                df.setMinimumFractionDigits(this.colDef.getNumberDigits());
                df.setMaximumFractionDigits(this.colDef.getNumberDigits());
                break;
            }
            default: {
                // no further formatting needed
                break;
            }
            }
            return df.format(value);
        }
    }

    ...

}
```

Comment: Thanks Per. Where is the variable currentlocale ? Is it a property?

Comment: I have added an explanation of currentLocale

Comment: I'm sorry but I have little experience with java. I put your code into my bean customizer and is giving the error 'colDef cannot be resolved or is not a field' on the line : switch (this.colDef.getNumberFmt()).

Comment: colDef is part of the constructor for a class that extends ViewColumnConverter. You need to have a working customizer bean with such a class in order to use my example. Have a look at my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/10373114/785061 that links to code on Github by Jesse Gallagher: https://github.com/jesse-gallagher/Domino-One-Offs/blob/master/mcl/reports/DynamicViewCustomizer.java#L390